# Rails Pluralize Not Working When Controller Fetches One Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I've been doing some testing in a simple Rails app.

In my controller, I assign an instance variable like this:

`@user = User.last`

This is strictly for testing — I have no good reason to pull the last user in this way.

In my view, I use the pluralize method to report the number of users. Of course, since I'm using `User.last`, there is only one.

In the view, the code is `<%= pluralize(@user.size, 'User') %>`.

When it runs the application throws a NoMethodError for `size`.

You would think that size would report 1 in this case but, for some reason, it doesn't.

I'm curious why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is a false claim. `pluralize` is just a helper, it doesn't matter where you use it.

In your case, @user is a single record. It doesn't have `size` method. That's true. So the error is expected, nothing wrong.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know a single record wouldn't have a size method. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. That's why one user can never be "users" :)

Comment: You can use `size` or `count` on an Array or ActiveRecord::Relation object. If `[@user]`, it's size is 1.